# Facebook like count removed

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have added a Facebook feed and like count on a website but after I like the page, the count is removed and replaced with 'You liked this'.

Is there a way to keep the count shown at all times? You can see by clicking the top facebook icon at http://www.artfido.com/listing.php?title=Boatwood&item_number=2736498541

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just tested on the link you provided, count does not disappear on like for me.

Comment: Did you try the TOP facebook icon? Not the bottom. THe top Facebook icon opens an overlay which you can then like inside that.